# Shell script replacing string with a little logic

Tags: shell

I have files that in-correctly contain

````
``` Some text ```
````

and I need to replace the ticks to pre

```
<pre> Some text </pre>
```

The trick is, the first pre doest have `/` but the seccond pre does.

Comment: Does the text ever span multiple lines?

Comment: Yes the some text could span multiple lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `awk`:

````
$ cat file
``` Some text ```
``` Some
text ```
$ gawk -v RS='```' -v ORS= 'NR>1{$0=(!(NR%2)?"<pre>":"</pre>")$0}1' file
<pre> Some text </pre>
<pre> Some
text </pre>
````

Comment: I was going to answer this question earlier with Python, but this is quite a nice solution and shorter too. :)